# DDL Create Trigger with create inside. oracle. Sql development

Tags: oracle

I want to  create a trigger that after create table, create another table_backup that have same value. Is this possible?

```
create or replace trigger aftercreatebackup
after create on schema
begin
  loop
  create table ora_dict_obj_name || '_backup' as select * from ora_dict_obj_name where 1=0;
  end loop;
end;
```

loop here because a error PLS-00103

Comment: First off, why?  What problem are you solving by creating a new table?  Second, if you're going to do this, you'd need to submit a job that does the `create table`.  And you'd need a way to prevent the trigger from looping indefinitely (i.e. don't create a backup table if the table name is already `_backup`).  Third, since identifiers are limited to 30 characters, what if the table name is more than 23 characters such that you can't add a 7 character suffix?  Fourth, you'd need to use dynamic SQL in the job that does the `create table` using `execute immediate`.

Comment: Oh, and you presumably want to consult `ora_dict_obj_type` to see whether the object being created is a table and to get rid of the pointless infinite loop.

Comment: Couldn't say it better than @JustinCave did ;-)